# PDO cannot find ODBC driver

Tags: oracle, pdo, odbc, database-connection, windows-7-x64

Trying to migrate to PDO for an ODBC connection to a remote database.

My system is Windows 7 Pro, with a FortiClient VPN connection to the remote domain, and Tunnel Mode connected.  (*Added in edit:* Running PHP 5.4, so PDO should be installed by default.)

The data source configuration in the Windows 7 ODBC Data Source Administrator is as follows (some names changed for security):

- Under *System DSN*:

  - *System Data Source Name* = 'TheBigDB'
  - *Driver* = 'Oracle in instantclient_11_2' *(64-bit)*
  - *TNS Service Name* = '10.10.1.20:1521/BIGDB'
  - *UserID* = 'BigDBUser'
  - All other settings are defaults for installation of driver

The following piece of PHP non-PDO code is able to create a connection usable for queries:

```
    if (!($myConn = odbc_connect('TheBigDB','BigDBUser','myPwd'))) {
        echo "No ODBC connection<br />";
    }
```

So I can connect to the database.  The problem is doing it in PDO.  The following PHP...

```
    try {
        $odbcConn = new PDO('odbc:Driver={Oracle in instantclient_11_2};Server=10.10.1.20:1521;Database=BIGDB;Uid=BigDBUser;Pwd=myPwd');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'PDO connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

... results in a *PDO connection failed: could not find driver* message.  My first try relied more heavily on the Data Sources Administrator; that looked like this:

```
    try {
        $odbcConn = new PDO('MyBigDB','BigDBUser','myPwd');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'PDO connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Same thing -- *could not find driver*.

So here's my question: **Given a Windows 7 system with ODBC through a VPN connection to an Oracle database that all seems to work without PDO, how do I migrate the connection parameters to create a PDO connection?**  Maybe a better question is why mess with PDO for the connection, but I keep reading that PDO is more secure, so I'm trying to use it.

Answer (score 2):

**More digging got me an answer.**  The correct syntax for creating a PDO object that uses a Windows Data Sources ODCB connection is not what I showed, but instead this (minus the try/catch):

```
    $myConn = new PDO('odbc:TheBigDB','BigDBUser','myPwd');
```

BUT... with PHP 5.4.12 using ODBC to touch an Oracle 11 DB, you need to edit the correct *php.ini* file (see [this WampServer forum topic](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,45057,45079) for a discussion of which of three *php.ini* files you need to edit).  Under *Dynamic Extensions*, uncomment `extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll` and `extension=php_pdo_oci.dll` (I did both; not sure which one did the trick...)

Another tip: In my scripts, neither `odbc_connect()` nor `PDO()` worked for me unless my connection was created in *Windows Data Sources Administrator* under the *System DSN* tab.  It did not work under *User DSN*.